# How to manage encryption keys on the cloud?

Tags: encryption, key, saas

I would like to provision services from a Software as a Service (SaaS) provider.
This is multitenant environment (multiple companies will be using a single instance of the application, with a single database, running on the same hardware and same OS).

Our company has a requirement to encrypt our data at rest.

Most of the guidance I have read states that the key should be kept with the customer or a third party and not with the cloud provider.

If I have the key; then every user in my company will need the key to access the file store once logged in? How would this work practically? Will the key be binded with my a users Username and Password?

Other option is to store the key in a configuration file on the cloud platform and managed by the cloud provider. But this creates another problem of securing the config file and the risk of having our key on a shared platform.

Where can the cloud provider store the key securely so that only I and my employees can use it?

What is best practice in terms of key management when having encrypted data on the cloud?

Best practice from my research states the following:

•   Store the key with the customer or 3rd party

•   Only authorised persons to access the key.

•   Do not store the key on the same platform as the data.

Answer (score 0):

> Most of the guidance I have read states that the key should be kept with the customer or a third party and not with the cloud provider.

It's easy to make the such statements, harder to implemet.

However - if it's all on cloud, data need to be shared, you have to share the key too somehow too.  I'd rather state the key should be stored separately from the encrypted data. Then you need to specify what "separately" is.

> If I have the key; then every user in my company will need the key to access the file store once logged in?
>   How would this work practically? Will the key be binded with my a users Username and Password?

When encrypting data at rest - **the key is needed by services providing the content, not the enduser itself**. I see no reason why the enduser would need an encryption key for "at-rest" encryption. As an exception would be if the key is encrypted using asymmetric encryption and user's private key is needed to decrypt the key and data.

> Where can the cloud provider store the key securely so that only I and my employees can use it?
>   What is best practice in terms of key management when having encrypted data on the cloud?
>   Best practice from my research states the following:, Store the key with the customer or 3rd party, Only authorised persons to access the key. Do not store the key on the same platform as the data.

Basically you listed your options. Depends what is "good enough" for you and if you are bound to some regulations.

Maybe you should not reinvent a wheel and see what a lot of other smart people did. Have a look at big cloud providers (AWS, Azure, Google, ..) how they approached this problem. You are not the first neither last having this requirement.

Every bigger cloud provider is having a place to manage the secrets and access to the secrets (e.g. AWS provides KMS and Secret Manager, Azure provides KeyVault, ...).

You may as well use 3rd party credential vault, but you need to store the service credentials somewhere as well.